# Button to perform a PHP script in a table issue

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I have set a script to show all members of my database in a table that have so called 'Pending Points' . In that table there's a button that an admin can click to send those pending points to 'Points' to the user in that row of the table and resetting the 'Pending Points' to 0. I have made the script to send these points but it doesn't seem to change anything even though it does give the success message. Any help is appreciated !

**Here's an image that will clarify:**
[image]

**Code to send the points (sendpoints.php):**

```
<?  
include ("connect.php");

$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM members WHERE pendingpoints > 0 ");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$send = $_POST['send'];

 if ($send) {

 mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE members SET points='$newpoints' WHERE    
     username='$username'");
 mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE members SET pendingpoints='0' WHERE   
     username='$username'");

         $username = $row['username'];
         $pendingpoints = $row['pendingpoints'];
         $points = $row['points'];
         $newpoints = $points + $pendingpoints;

 echo "Succesfully changed points for that user";

 }

 ?>
```

**Code to show the table:**

```
<?
include ("connect.php");
$submit = $_POST['submit'];
if ($submit) {

 $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM members WHERE pendingpoints > 0 ");
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,         MYSQLI_ASSOC);

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
 $username = $row['username'];
 $pendingpoints = $row['pendingpoints'];
 $points = $row['points'];
 $newpoints = $points + $pendingpoints;
 $ip = $row['ip'];

 echo "<table border='1'> 

 <tr>
     <td><b>Username:</b></td>   
     <td><b>Pendingpoints:</b></td>     
     <td><b>IP:</b></td>     
     <td><b>Confirm Points:</b></td>


 </tr> 
 <tr>
     <form id='1' action='sendpoints.php' method='post'>
     <td> $username </td>  
     <td> $pendingpoints </td>       
     <td> $ip </td>      
     <td><input type='submit' class='classname' name='send' value='Send'></form></td> 
 </tr>   

 <br> </table>"; 
}
}


?>
```

Comment: How are you accessing `$row` in `sendpoints.php` ?

Comment: Okay I defined row but it's still not changing anything nor giving any errors (updated post)

Comment: `$username = $row['username'];` these variables should be below your select query

Comment: I changed that but still same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding you want to send points on button click only to specific person but in your code your doing something else..

**note:** i added hidden variable in your form to send points to only that specific user

```
<?  
include ("connect.php");


 if (isset($_POST['send'])) {

$username=$_POST'username'];
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='$username' ");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$pendingpoints = $row['pendingpoints'];
$points = $row['points'];
$newpoints = $points + $pendingpoints;


 $q=mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE members SET points='$newpoints',pendingpoints=0 WHERE    
     username='$username'");

     if($q){
 echo "Succesfully changed points for that user";
 }
 }

 ?>
```

**Code to show the table:**

```
<?
include ("connect.php");
$submit = $_POST['submit'];
if ($submit) {

 $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM members WHERE pendingpoints > 0 ");
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,         MYSQLI_ASSOC);

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
 $username = $row['username'];
 $pendingpoints = $row['pendingpoints'];
 $points = $row['points'];
 $newpoints = $points + $pendingpoints;
 $ip = $row['ip'];

 echo "<table border='1'> 

 <tr>
     <td><b>Username:</b></td>   
     <td><b>Pendingpoints:</b></td>     
     <td><b>IP:</b></td>     
     <td><b>Confirm Points:</b></td>


 </tr> 
 <tr>
     <td> $username </td>  
     <td> $pendingpoints </td>       
     <td> $ip </td>      
     <td><form id='1' action='sendpoints.php' method='post'><input type='submit' class='classname' name='send' value='Send'><input type='hidden' name='username' value='$username'></form></td> 
 </tr>   

 <br> </table>"; 
}
}


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first script `$row` is not defined.

Edit: since the code was updated, the logic seems to be incorrect.  You need to pull username from $_POST, and use this in the update.

However, two big problems: you are not handling escaping of special chars like  '.  This can break the form, and open up mysql injection security holes.

Comment: Ok... and the OP should do what(?) in order to make it work? You're only saying it's not defined, so have I; in a comment which is what this is.

Comment: There's not enough info to say what it should be.  I'm guessing $row needs to change to $_POST

Comment: True. I'm not going to touch this one because it WILL only open up a can of worms.